# openpyxl: adding values to cells using a for loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I am trying to increase the value inside of each cell by 1.

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb['Sheet']
age = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value='age')
gender = sheet.cell(row=1, column=2, value='gender')
genre = sheet.cell(row=1, column=3, value='genre')

val = 20

for row in range(2, 11):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1)
    cell.value(val)

wb.save('music.xlsx')
```

I keep getting an error:

```
line 14, in <module>
    cell.value(val)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

I know that there is a lot of errors in my code, however I do not know how to fix it.

Comment: I suggest you work your way through the openpyxl tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In the cell object, value is not a method, it's property.

So use below code:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from openpyxl import Workbook

wb = Workbook()
sheet = wb['Sheet']
age = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1, value='age')
gender = sheet.cell(row=1, column=2, value='gender')
genre = sheet.cell(row=1, column=3, value='genre')

val = 20

for row in range(2, 11):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=row, column=1)
    cell.value = val

wb.save('music.xlsx')
```